# Nested allocatable components

Tags: object, fortran, gfortran, allocation

I found a weird behaviour in gfortran 7 and 8, when I try to nest derived types with allocatable components.

Is this a bug in Gfortran or forbidden by the Standard?
Am I right in my understanding, that the only workaround is to use pointers instead?

```
module test_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: A_t, C_t

    type :: A_t
        integer, allocatable :: x(:)
    end type

    type :: B_t
        integer :: x
    end type

    type :: C_t
        ! this works
!         integer, allocatable :: S(:)
        ! this works
!         type(B_t), allocatable :: S(:)
        ! this does not work
        type(A_t), allocatable :: S(:)
    end type

contains

end module

program test_allocatable_compoenten
    use test_mod, only: A_t, C_t
    implicit none

    block
        type(C_t) :: orbs

        orbs = C_t()
    end block
end program
```

Comment: What is the behaviour that you see (compared with what you expect)?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate based on what happened when I tried to compile with gfortran. If you see something different, please update the question with more detail. Using `orbs=C_t(NULL())` (rather than having pointer components) looked fine to me, just like in the linked question.